# I backed up wamp folder and formatted my PC, phpmyadmin says x table doesnt exist

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I backed up wamp folder in my USB. 
It is in my USB currently. I downloaded that version of WAMP and i moved my sites datas in `bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data` and www. I can view my site using localhost but mysql data doesnt work. Phpmyadmin shows table names but when i click on it it says this table doesnt exist.

[image]

Comment: please add sample codes or error codes to your question.

Comment: @IvanBarayev but there is no code? i formatted my pc and just want to my database work like it did before the format. i backed up whole wamp file before formating my pc. i moved mysql datas to bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data. And site folders to www. site is working but database is not working. when i go to phpmyadmin and click on database it shows table names but when i click on table it says it doesnt exist.

Comment: ok find your my.ini file and open it with any editor. look for path of DB

Comment: @IvanBarayev i added a picture.

" datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data "

Comment: open your task manager ( Görev Yöneticisi) fint mysql*.exe right click on it and End process (İşlemi Sonlandır).Then go to C:/Windows/ folder find my.ini file and delete it. after restart your computer and start your mysql again and try it.

Comment: @IvanBarayev there is no mysql*.exe running. wampserver is green and online. i can go to phpmyadmin and localhost site. and my site is running but database not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you restore the complete folder

```
\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data
```

from your thumb drive to your reinstalled WAMPServer

INNODB database are stored in a file called

```
\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\ibdata1
```

the sub folders (with names of your databases) in here hold only table definition, schema data and not actual data.

Even if you have set MYSQL to create a file per table, some information is still held in the `ibdata1` file